# Create mongoose reference of models in differents files

Tags: reference, mongoose, schema, models

I need to create references to 2 models which are in different files. My models are:

```
Profesor
Curso
```

I want `Curso` to have a reference to a `Profesor`. My problem is that when the models `Curso` is being created, the model `Profesor` does not exist yet.

> MissingSchemaError Schema hasn't been registered for model Profesor

If the reference is to the model `Alumno` there isn´t problem because `Alumno` is created before `Curso` right?

Comment: Alumno.server.model
Curso.server.model
Profesor.server.model
User.server.model

Answer (score 1):

Just create all your schemas first and then register your models. And do all of this when you bootstrap your app, before anything else. Then you won't have such issues. An example from the docs, where two schema reference each other:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

Comment: but my problem was that the schemas were in different files and 'Curso' was created before that 'Profesor' Because C < P.
I have solved this problem renaming model 'Curso' by v.Curso, because 
P < V.
I can not think of another solution

Comment: I don't understand why your files are loaded in alphabetical order. In the mongoose apps I have seen the order of loading is defined by the order of require statements that require those files. So, if you require your professor file first everything should be fine. How do you load your model files?

Comment: Right, I'll check the require, to see how it is loading files.
I created these files with a Yeoman generator, so perhaps have been added alphabetically?
Thanks for answering

Comment: I have finded the error, I were doing require of the model when it isn´t necesary, only I need the name to the reference, Not the model complete